# How to partition my hard disk

Tags: filesystems, partition

How to partitioning hard disk for two different linux system on the GPT/UEFI.
Size of disk 500gb.

I ask because of the fact the disk is limited to 4 primary partition.

I want to have 2 partitions on each system and one common.
1 section will be EFI

Comment: There's no limitation of 4 "primary" parititions on GPT - GPT doesn't have primary partitions at all.

Comment: ie restrictions on the 4 primary partitions are only for mbr?

Comment: Yes, the primary partition business is for MBR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GPT can have as many partitions as you want*. Therefore, you can have them all. Most of the time when I partition my disc, I set up `/home` on separate partition for my data(music, images, etc). This has a benefit of being able to reinstall my system without losing data.

So we already have 3 partitions: `swap`(double the ram), `/`(I give it 1/2 of disc space I have), and `/home` (another 1/2). You can also make separate `/var` for programs, or `/boot`, but they aren't really needed - you'll do just fine with these 3.

As for filesystems, here's what I go with:

`swap`: swap

`/`, `/home` : ext4

`/boot` : ext2

I basically take these 3(+ I have `/boot`), set up swap and boot, then divide rest in half, approximately. Should work for you too.

`* Given you don't want insanely many partitions.`

Comment: thanks, but how about partitioning in gpt for 2 system? I tink for each linux system i do 2 partitions  ( / and /home ). And common its efi and swap.

Comment: You need to decide by yourself. You will need two `/`, one `swap`, but I'd say that one `/home` should be sufficient.

Comment: I did not even think that this can and will be correct.
 Even for different distro like gentoo and arch?)

Comment: @DmitryKorzhov [this shows how you could do it](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55224/a-common-home-partition-for-multiple-linux-distributions)  - I was talking from my perspective; I guess that's why your question got closed as opinion-based. You *can* have one `/home`, and it would be okay, considering you don't have that much space - but if you don't need that much, you can have two `/home` and one partition with other data, that both systems would use.